# How to clean gedit's and other editor's find&replace history?

Tags: gedit, history, cleanup

I have started working on a new project using `gedit` on ubuntu 12.04. The problem i am facing now is that, all previously searched terms are still there when i click on the drop down arrow in search box of find&replace menu and i have to select from a long list of search terms.

How can i clean those histories of find&replace?
[image]

Comment: The Answer in original post(as per everyone) is not providing any solution and i am still getting those histories. I deleted all recently-used-xbel(there are two of them) with out any change, i again did that thing and logout and login again to see no change. It would be appreciated if duplicate mark will be removed as that question is not identical. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search items are stored in gsettings/dconf. The ~/config/dconf/user file can't be edited so use dconf-editor. Go to `org.gnome.gedit.state.history-entry` & remove as desired or reset to default ['']

or from cli

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.state.history-entry search-for-entry "['']"
```

for previous replace items

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.state.history-entry replace-with-entry "['']"
```

Comment: Can also do `reset` as `$ gsettings reset org.gnome.gedit.state.history-entry search-for-entry
`.

Answer (score 0):

type in terminal:

whereis gedit.history

then you find the paths where history-file is located and linked.

Comment: But which are to be deleted? Isn't there any direct command?

Comment: You want `rm ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` see the link I gave above as this is a duplicate.

Comment: GEdit doesn't store its find-and-replace history in recently-used.xbel...

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, i think #DaboRoss is correct, as the solution provided in the original answer is not working for my problem. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

And for pluma (mate text editor, which is fork of gedit 2)

```
dconf write '/org/mate/pluma/history-replace-with' "['']"
dconf write '/org/mate/pluma/history-search-for' "['']"
```

Answer (score 0):

XED Editor:

Wipe the search history:

```
gsettings reset org.x.editor.state.history-entry history-search-for
```

Wipe the replace history:

```
gsettings reset org.x.editor.state.history-entry history-replace-with
```